# Cascading a delete to a many-to-many association table?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a problem with cascading a delete. I have two tables, and they 
are mapped many-to-many:

```
class File(object): pass 
file_table = Table('file', metadata, 
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True), 
        Column('filename', String(255)), 
} 

class FileHost(object): pass 
file_host = Table('host', metadata, 
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True ), 
        Column('name', String(255)), 
) 

file_hosted = Table('file_hosted', metadata, 
        Column('id_host', Integer, ForeignKey('host.id')), 
        Column('id_file', Integer, ForeignKey('file.id')) 
) 

session.mapper(File, file_table, properties={ 
    'host': relation(FileHost, secondary=file_hosted, backref='files', 
                        cascade='all,delete-orphan', single_parent=True) 
}) 
session.mapper(FileHost, file_host)
```

This is the error I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: 
(IntegrityError) update or delete on table "file" violates
foreign key constraint "file_hosted_id_file_fkey" on table "file_hosted" 
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(50905) is still referenced from table "file_hosted".
```

Has anybody got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

I also asked the question [on the sqlalchemy mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/f73aa1608786ce30), and got the right answer:

> You are telling SQLAlchemy to cascade File deletes to FileHost, but you 
>   want it the other way around. You can fix this by moving the 
>   cascade='all,delete-orphan' and single_parent=True clauses into the 
>   backref. You also probably want uselist=False.

```
session.mapper(File, file_table, properties={ 
    'host': relation(FileHost, 
                     backref=backref('files', 
                                     cascade='all,delete-orphan', 
                                     single_parent=True), 
                     secondary=file_hosted, 
                     uselist=False) 
})
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to cascade: deletion of `File` to delete its `FileHost`, deletion of `FileHost` to delete its `File`s, or both?

Comment: When I delete a `File` it should delete the appropriate rows in `file_hosted`.

Comment: can you add a code snippet that generates this error?

Comment: As it looks, you code is fine and should be working.

Anyways, why do you need a secondary table for `N-to-1` relationship instead of putting a `ForeignKey` directly into `file` table?

Comment: One file can be on many hosts, and one host has many files, therefore I need a many-to-many relationship I think.  

I've found the solution elsewhere, and will include it in an edit.

Comment: @tom: please add your solution as an answer. Handling order dependencies in SA is a common issue, people will appreciate having the solution at hand.

Answer (score 7):

It should be noted that while this wasn't the problem in this particular case, you may still get this error if you don't include `ondelete="CASCADE"` in the declaration of your foreign keys.  Even after declaring `cascade="all,delete"` in my relationships, I was still getting this error until I added the `ondelete` attribute.  You may want to add `onupdate="CASCADE"` as well.

Comment: In order to clarify this a little.. `ondelete="CASCADE"` instructs the DB itself to create cascade deletes on the foreign keys. `cascade="all,delete"` is an instruction for sqlalchemy to manage the cascading. See the green box just down from this link: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#delete